# Reflection Property Info :How to show only some Properties at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

my code:

```
    namespace Reflection

    {

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type t = typeof(Product);
            PropertyInfo[] proInfo = t.GetProperties();
            foreach (var item in proInfo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Product
    {

        public int ProId { get; set; }
        public string ProName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

I get all properties names as output.But I dont want to show ProId and Decription in the output .How can i do that????

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add an attribute to fields you either do/don't want to show in your list, and then filter them out after doing `GetProperties()` by looking for said attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, if you only have 2 properties you don't want to show is to filter on them specifically. You can use LINQ's **[Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311043.aspx)** for this:

```
    Type t = typeof(Product);
    PropertyInfo[] proInfo = t.GetProperties().Where( p => p.Name != "ProdId" && p.Name != "Description").ToArray() ;

    foreach (var item in proInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
```

Or even something like this:

```
string[] dontShow = { "ProId", "Descrpition" };

Type t = typeof(MyObject);
PropertyInfo[] proInfo = t.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => !dontShow.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();
```